# clearInterval in if doesn't work

Tags: javascript, intervals

I have something like this:

```
function myFunction()
{
    var testVar;
    if(txt == "Maybe")
    {
        txt == "No";
        testVar = setInterval(function(){ zrobTo() }, 1000);
    }
    else if(txt == "No")
   {
        txt == "Maybe";
        clearInterval(testVar);
    }
}
```

When `clearInterval` isn't in if then code is working, but I wanna have this in if. Is it possible?

Comment: You're redeclaring `testvar` each time so `clearInterval` will never clear the interval set. Move it further up the scope, outside `myFunction`

Comment: @haim770 I've read the code again. Can you point out how the OP isn't overwriting that interval pointer with `var testVar`?

Comment: @haim770 He's overwriting it **by** redeclaring `testVar`.

Comment: @zerkms, You're right. Sorry, missed that point.

Comment: Also, the double equals are used for comparisons, not for setting something equal to something else. So you should keep `txt == "No"` in the parenthesis of your if statements, but in the brackets, use `txt = "Maybe";`

Comment: @mpadittech I know this. That was only mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the setInterval is never leaving the function. Since the variable is local, it is deleted when the function ends. There is no way around this that I have found. D=